# Removing square bracket symbols in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I hava a df with 10 column with rows inserted as a single element list.  How can I remove the '[]' from all rows?

I tried for one column:  `df['DAT'] = df['DAT'].map(lambda x: x.replace('[]',''))`

Comment: It seems your column is of type list. YOu should extract ie `x[0]` check the first answer given by anurag

Comment: if i use x[0] in a column like [GEOM] it returns G, i need GEOM

Comment: HOW  is that even possible? `[GEOM]` or `"GEOM"`? Can you include that column in your question?

Comment: Just did @Onyambu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via `astype()` and `strip()`:

```
df['DAT'] = df['DAT'].astype(str).str.strip("['']")
```

**OR**

Try with `pd.eval()` and `map()`:

```
df['DAT']=pd.eval(df['DAT'])
df['DAT']=df['DAT'].map(lambda x:x[0])
```

Comment: Nice one @Anurag

Comment: @Anurag I could cast to string but I got '2021-01-29' instead of 2021-01-29

Comment: What difference are you expecting? Do you need a `datetime` object @StatsPy?

Comment: I have several columns with that format, all object and when i try to apply raplace it says that list objetc has no atribute replace.  I ust want all columns as string without [] or ''

Comment: @StatsPy updated answer....kindlya have a look ***:)***

Answer (score 2):

Use `Series.str.replace`

```
df['DAT'] = df.DAT.str.replace('\[|\]', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned the type of column in the question. I have assumed it as `object` or `string`. Hence you get that output.